# How to set the encoding in a TableView

Tags: java, javafx, utf-8, character-encoding, tableview

my TableView doesn't show the german *Umlaut* like **ä ö ü** although
my console shows me the right characters for Düsseldorf, Köln, München, etc.

Do I have to set a charset or the like in a tableView?

[image: screenshot]

Here is an example

```
TableColumn<TextData, String> column;
TableView<TextData> table;
ObservableList<TextData> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

...
...
//part of main code
Task<ObservableList<TextData>> task = new Task() {

@Override
protected Object call() throws Exception {  

    IOFileOperations io = new IOFileOperations(fileName); 
    data = io.getData(); 
    colNumSize=io.getNumberOfColumns(); 

    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
            public void run() {

                for(int i=0;i<colNumSize;i++) {
                    final int x=i; 
                    column = new TableColumn<>("["+x+"]");  
                    //populate the columns with data
                    column.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().dataProperty(x));                             
                    table.getColumns().add(column);
                }   
            table.setItems(data);   
            }           
        });
        return null;
    }
};
new Thread(task).start();

//method getData in class IOFileOperations
 public ObservableList<TextData> getData() {
    int numRow=results.length; //<-results a string of Array (String [][] results)
    int numCol=results[0].length;
    for(int i=0;i<numRow;i++) list.add(new TextData(i,numCol, results));   
    return list;
}

//class TextData
public class TextData {

    public StringProperty [] dataValue; 

    public TextData(int row, int numCol, String loadedText [][]) {
        this.dataValue = new StringProperty[numCol];
        for(int i=0;i<numCol;i++) dataValue[i] = new SimpleStringProperty(loadedText[row][i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Those names work for me by defining them in a collection. How are you populating your TableView?

Comment: Works fine for me too. Please [edit] your question to include a [MCVE].

Comment: @James_D alright, I've added an example

Comment: @Peter please have a look at my code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the problem is with how you're reading in your data in this class `IOFileOperations`

Without including that, we can't help isolate the exact problem in your implementation. 
 Below i've included an example to recreate the issue including how to correct it with the following text file:

> Düsseldorf 
>  Köln 
>  München

Which should help you debug and correct your own implementation

---

```
public class City {
    private int id;
    private String name;

    public City(int id, String name){
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

**Reading in the data:** 
Note that at this step we can provide the charset we want to use. With UTF-8 everything will display as expected, however if you switch between the commented line the umlauts won't be recognised

```
ObservableList<City> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
File file = new File("test.txt");
//Charset charset = StandardCharsets.US_ASCII;
Charset charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
int currentId = 0;

try(BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), charset))) {
    String line = reader.readLine();

    while (line != null) {
        data.add(new City(currentId, line));
        line = reader.readLine();
        currentId++;
    }
}
```

And setting up the TableView:

```
TableView<City> tableView = new TableView();
TableColumn idColumn = new TableColumn("Id");
idColumn.setCellValueFactory(
        new PropertyValueFactory<>("id"));
TableColumn cityColumn = new TableColumn("City");
cityColumn.setCellValueFactory(
        new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));

 tableView.getColumns().setAll(idColumn, cityColumn);
 tableView.getItems().addAll(data);
```

---

**Difference between charsets:**

[image]
[image]

Comment: I get the right umlauts with *charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;*